# Xcode intermittently doesn't find xcframework

Tags: xcode, xcframework

Xcode sometimes doesn't find my xcframework for incremental builds.

- Error is `ld: framework not found [framework]` where `[framework]` is the name of my xcframework.
- Once it fails, repeated incremental builds will also fail.
- A clean build always fixes it.
- The issue started when I switched from normal frameworks to xcframeworks.
- I followed the instructions in this WWDC video to create the xcframework: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/416/

I diffed the link commands between and incremental and clean build, and there was no difference. This would seem to be an Xcode bug.
I'm using Xcode 11.4.1.

Comment: Not at all. It’s a compliment. There’s lots of evidence that you are absolutely right; xcframeworks are still not ready for prime time. You have a great use case and you’ve done your homework.  Filing the bug will help you, us, and Apple. There’s nothing we can do about it; a fix must come from Apple. Meanwhile maybe don’t use xcframeworks?

Comment: Well, I tend to know what I'm doing. I've filed many bugs, but it takes serious time to break things out into reproducible cases I can send to Apple. Once I spent an entire week building a repro case for a bug in the Metal compiler backend. So it's always in my interest to see if someone has some insight in various places before filing.

Answer (score 2):

There are some issues with XCFrameworks that could cause that particular error, maybe you have this .xcframework in more than one target? Then you are in situation when Xcode only do one extraction of `.framework` from `.xcframewok` and report missing error if another target start building. You can [look at my write up](https://pyckamil.github.io/programming,/xcframework,/xcode/2020/05/09/everything-wrong-with-xcframeworks.html) of issue that I did face in the past.